# OOM when defining keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I cannot define the following model which is built using the functional api:

```
input = layers.Input(shape=get_img_input_shape(True), name="input")
covn01 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(input)
acti01 = layers.Activation('relu')(covn01)
pool01 = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(acti01)
covn02 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(pool01)
acti02 = layers.Activation('relu')(covn02)
pool02 = layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2)(acti02)
covn03 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3))(pool02)
acti02 = layers.Activation('relu')(covn02)
pool02 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same')(acti02)

#flat = layers.Flatten()(pool03)

model_one = Model(inputs = input, outputs=pool02)

model_two = Model(inputs = input, outputs=pool02)
```

```
concat_feature_layer = layers.concatenate([model_one.output, model_two.output])
flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()(concat_feature_layer)
fully_connected_dense_big = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dropout_one = layers.Dropout(0.3)(fully_connected_dense_big)
fully_connected_dense_small = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(dropout_one)
dropout_two = layers.Dropout(0.3)(fully_connected_dense_small)
fully_connected_dense_class = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dropout_two)

model = Model(
    inputs=[model_one.input, model_two.input],
    outputs=fully_connected_dense_class
)

model.summary()
```

I keep recieving the following error:

ResourceExhaustedError: failed to allocate memory [Op:Mul]

and seems to be happening after the flatten layer.

i'm using a 2060 GPU. I have built a similar model but much bigger on my mac with 8GB Ram and it runs fine.

The outputs of model_one and model_two looks like:

[output layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L1wY.png)

I have tried:

Reducing the image resoulution (shape), adding flattening layers to each sub-model and remove flattening layer after concat layer and removed layers without any success...

Comment: I've sometimes run into this for no apparent reasons and restarting the interactive kernel fixed it.

Comment: I am experience the same problem with tensorflow 2.7. Defining model shouldn't allocate memory but it does and somehow fails.